# Bulb not lighting up if resistor is used

Tags: voltage

I have a `12v` adapter and small bulb of about `3.8v`. If i give power to bulb with 12 volt adapter and with 100ohm to 10k ohm it doesn't light up and if i directly give it power without the resistor it fuses.

This is the bulb i have

[image: Bulb]

When i give power to bulb with 9v battery without resistors it light up perfectly fine.

Adapter gives `1.5amp` (mentioned on sticker)

How can i light up this bulb with 12volt adapter without blowing(fuse) it up?. I am not much experienced with electronics.

Comment: Is there any marking on the bulb or base?  Voltage or current, or just a type number?  Without some specifications on the bulb, it is hard to comment.

Comment: `3.8v' written on the packet it came in

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i light up this bulb with 12volt adapter without blowing(fuse) it up. I am not much experienced with elelctronics

Comment: If the bulb is rated for 3.8 volts, it is no wonder it blows when given 12 volts.  I'd expect it to have a very short life with 9 volts.  Without knowing the current it expects to draw at 3.8 volts, or the type number (which would allow us to look up the specs), we can't say what resistance would be appropriate to alow it to operate from 12 volts.

Comment: When checking with multi meter set on 200M ohm it gives ouput `00.9`.

Comment: 9V batteries have very high internal resistance (I've seen as much as 50Ohm). At 0.3A, the battery terminal voltage probably dipped quite significantly (hence not burning out the bulb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a reference to a #13 radio pilot lamp rated at 3.8 volts, 0.3 amp.  To operate that lamp from a 12 volt supply, you need a resistor that will drop 8.2 volts at 0.3 amp.  Ohm's Law says that a 27 ohm resistor would work.

If your lamp draws a different current, the you would need a different resistor, but 27 ohms should be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanx i will try and will update you.

Comment: After more calculation, I find you'd need a 2.5 watt resistor, so you really should try to find some 12 volt bulbs (or perhaps use an LED).

Comment: adding 25ohm resistor did work.

Answer (score 1):

Many adapters of the type you describe are unregulated giving a higher-than-nominal output when unloaded or even lightly loaded. They tend use the load current of their intended powered device to pull the output voltage down towards the nominal value (12V in your case).

You say that you think your MES lamp is 5V and that the adapter has a capability of 1.5A.  Your lamp probably draws between 60 and 300mA, consequently your adaptor is only lightly loaded at perhaps 6% of its capability, causing a high output voltage to appear across your lamp and 'blowing' it!

The value of any series resistance is calculated from Ohm's Law using the formula: R = V/I  where V is the difference between the nominal supply voltage (12V) and the lamp's voltage, which in this case gives us the result of 7V.

The value for I is the nominal lamp current, say 100mA (or 0.01A).  This gives a resistor value of 7/0.01 = 70 ohms.  The nearest E12 resistor value is 68 ohms.  If the lamp lights with this value of resistor but is somewhat dim, it means your lamp requires more current (assuming the supply is as described).  Try fitting a lower value  resistor, say 47 ohms until you reach a satisfactory brilliance.

Your question raises a number of other issues inherent in this situation, such as the required power rating of the resistor and the very fact that whilst this solution is a simple one, it represents a low efficiency solution owing to the energy that is wasted as heat in the resistor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the resistance of the bulb is probably very low, and you need to use a resistor roughly equal to the resistance value of the bulb, to equalize the voltage drop across both components. The 12v is too high for your 5v bulb, so that's why it burns out when you connect it directly to the 12v. I'm assuming you're connecting it in a parallel?

Comment: When checking with multi meter set on 200M ohm it gives ouput 00.9

Comment: So probably 1 ohm, which sounds about right, if you connect a 2 ohm resistor across the bulb, you'll drop appx 8volts across the resistor and 4 volts across the bulb, which should be about right.

Comment: Thanx i will try and will update you.

Comment: @philbrooksjazz: he should connect the resistor in series with the bulb, not "across" it (I'd understand "across" as "in parallel", which won't do any good.)  Don't forget that the resistance of an incandescent lamp increases as it heat up, so he would want a significantly higher resistance than you suggest.

Comment: So, be careful on one issue - I think Peter's ans. is for a series circuit, and if you're using that, your resistor power rating needs to be close to the bulb, even for a small flashlight bulb it's prob. 1.5 watts, so if you use a standard 1/4 watt resistor is could burn up the resistor. All the current flows through all the components in a series circuit.

Comment: Yes - Peter, you're correct I'm a little rusty on this, what was I thinking parallel will just blow the bulb! the resistor should be in the 20-40 ohm range, but the resistor needs to equal in power rating to the lamp, other wise it will run very hot or fuse.

Comment: don't do that. The resistance of a bulb changes around 10x from cold (off) to hot (on). The resistance you measure (say 1 ohm) increases to ~ 10 ohm when the bulb is lit. The appropriate resistance to use is the 27 ohm above, not 2 ohm.